# Como Diminuir complexidade de uma função com dois Loops em Python

Tags: python, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Essa função retorna o número de pares em que `A[i] > A[j]` para  `1 < i < j < n`

```
def calc(A):
    cont = i = j = 0
    while i < len(A):
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(A):
            if A[i] > A[j]:
                cont += 1
            j += 1
        i += 1
    print(cont)
```

Suponha uma lista `L = [3, 2, 5, 2, 1]`, então `Calc(L) = 7`, porque `3 > 2`, `3 > 2`,`3 > 1` na primeira iteração, `2 > 1`, na segunda iteração `5 > 2` , `5 > 1` na terceira iteração e `2 > 1` na última iteração. Qual estrutura de dados que seja do tipo divisão e conquista faria com que o algoritmo acima execute mais rápido?

Comment: A não ser que saiba de algo que não sabemos, não parece que seja possível. Na verdade con certeza e detalhe nem sabemos o que quer alcançar.

Comment: gostaria de reduzir para que no mínimo seja O(n^2) no pior caso. Deve existir alguma maneira, é um exercício do livro de algoritmos, ele sugere usar alguma estrutura de dados de divisão e conquista, mas já to pensando a um bom tempo e não identifico nenhum que se aplicaria

Comment: Mas está com essa complexidade, no pior ou melhor caso. No livro deve ter uma definição melhor do problema, é o que eu falei, você só postou o algoritmo disse que quer que seja feito melhor. Eu cheguei pensar em algumas coisas, mas com a informação que temos essas coisas não se aplicariam. Claro que eu posso ter deixando escapar algo. Mas sem algo que diga diferente seu problema exige que todas as combinações de pares possível devem ser comparadas, até mesmo quando os mesmos elementos são comparados de novo mas agora invertidos em relação ao que já havia sido comparados.Até um *sort* é + fácil

Comment: um exemplo de input usado é a lista `L = [3, 2, 5, 2, 1]` tem resultado `calc(L) = 7`. Acho que não são todos os pares que devem ser comparados, o primeiro elemento compara com todos, mas o penúltimo só compara com o último. O livro explicitamente pede para que esse código seja recriado em modelo divisão e conquista, mas não sei qual estrutura utilizar

Comment: Se realmente precisa andar pelos pares possíveis tais que `i < j`, de toda sorte iria precisar fazer boa parte dessas comparações. Por mais esperta que fosse a estrutura de dados por baixo dos panos, no pior dos casos continuaria quadrática

Comment: @Pirategull Então você sabe que coisas que nós não sabemos. Você precisaria afirmar que não precisa ser todos, achar é diferente de ser. Muda o resultado. Oque você está falando dá para fazer em um *sort* porque vai pra um lado o que é menor e para o outro o que é maior, o seu caso ainda tem o que fazer com os que forem iguais. Na hora que inverte tem outra decisão a tomar. A não ser que o enunciado diga que não precisa comprar os pares na outra ordem. Aí fica bem fácil reduzir bem, mas novamente, sua pergunta não fala nisso.

Comment: Eu estou quase tendo certeza que tem algo que você não está dizendo. Ou o livro pode ser ruim. Do jeito que você está falando não dá pra dividir nada, a não ser que estivesse falando de separar em *threads*.

Comment: Tentei melhorar a compreensão re-editando a pergunta, agora botei tudo que eu tenho de informação do livro

Comment: Este problema que está tentando resolver chama-se *Contagem de Inversões*. Um algoritmo do tipo divisão e conquista que resolve este problema com mais eficiência é o *merge sort*. Existem diversos links que explicam o merge sort na internet. Exemplo: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/ Sobre o problema de contagem de inversões, veja: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/ ou https://medium.com/@ssbothwell/counting-inversions-with-merge-sort-4d9910dc95f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparando só 2 a 2 não é possível.

Mas se for um algoritmo "real" e não algo teórico, você pode, dentro da função mesmo, ir construindo uma lista em paralela, esta sendo ordenada, e aí fica bem mais simples - porque é possível fazer uma busca binária.

Aí você vai gastar O(log(n)) para ir construindo a lista ordenada, acho que a comparação final fica O(n log(n))

Aí, sim, para manter a ordenação dos items já vistos, e ter uma busca binária, o mais legal talvez seja criar uma classe pra fazer isso - nesse caso já puxamos uma da manga aqui, por que criar esse tipo de classe em Python é bem tranquilo. A biblioteca padrão implementa um heap - que pode inserir e extrair elementos em ordem - mas não dá pra usar busca binária em um heap.

A minha classe de sequencia ordenada, no entanto, usa uma lista de Python, com inserções no meio, para manter a ordenaçao - inserções no meio de uma lista em Python são relaticamente custosas, apesar de serem em código nativo - mas em termos de complexidade algoritmica são O(N) também - Se quiser absorver esse custo, então tem que customizar a própria lista com uma estrutura de dados de lista ligada - bem simples.

Se for levar esse código pra dentro de algum projeto, sugiro herdar o SortedSeq de
`abc.collections.MutableSequence` - e implementar os 3 ou 4 métodos a mais
que são sugeridos lá - `__setitem__, __getitem__, __delitem__, __len__, __insert__` se não me engano. Os valroes especiais que uso na primeira linha
também ficam mais bonitos se forem um `enum.Enum`.

```py
MATCH = 0; PREV = -3; POST=-2; NOTFOUND = -1

class SortedSeq:
    def __init__(self, initial=None):
        self.data = []
        if initial:
            for item in initial:
                self.push(item)

    def _find(self, item, start=0, end=None):
        if not self.data:
            return NOTFOUND, 0
        if end == None:
            end = len(self.data)
        if item == self.data[start]:
            return MATCH, start
        if item == self.data[end - 1]:
            return MATCH, end - 1

        middle = (start + end) // 2

        if item == self.data[middle]:
            return MATCH, middle

        if middle == start:
            value = self.data[start]
            return PREV if value < item else POST, start

        if self.data[middle] >= item:
            return self._find(item, start, middle)
        else:
            return self._find(item, middle, end)

    def count_before(item):
        sit, pos = self._find(item)
        if sit in (MATCH, PREV):
            return pos
        return 0


    def find(self, item):
        matched, index = self._find(item)
        if matched == MATCH:
            return index
        return NOTFOUND

    def push(self, item):
        sit, pos = self._find(item)

        if sit == NOTFOUND:
            self.data.append(item)
        elif sit == POST:
            self.data.insert(pos, item)
        else:
            self.data.insert(pos + 1, item)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"SortedSeq([{self.data}])"

# Disclaimer - não sei se você quer contar 
# os items já vistos que forem iguais ao 
# que está sendo olhado - se não quiser, tem que 
# modificar o "count_before" acima.
def calc(A):
    count = i = j = 0
    seem = SortedSeq()
    for i, item in enumerate(A):
        count += seem.count_before(item)
        seem.push(item)
    return count
```